# Mock call object method (Mockito Junit5 Spring)

Tags: java, spring, mockito, thymeleaf, junit5

I try to mock the thymeleaf template engine.

My test class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class MailServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private MailService mailService;
    
    @Mock private JavaMailSender mailSender;
    @Mock private TemplateEngine templateEngine;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setMockOutput() {
        doReturn("<html>Template processed String</html>").when(templateEngine.process(any(String.class), any(IContext.class)));
    }

    @Test
    public void testNewMailBoxMail() throws MessagingException, IOException {
                
        mailService.newMailBoxMail("M.", "nom", "adresse@email.fr");

        ...
    }
```

I got a lot of trouble with the process method parameter (`org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException`) and I'm not sure that they are OK.

As the test reach the `doReturn` line I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Template cannot be null
    at org.thymeleaf.util.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:37)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateSpec.<init>(TemplateSpec.java:314)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1048)
    at fr.strasbourg.accountManagement.service.MailServiceTest.setMockOutput(MailServiceTest.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:515)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeMethodInExtensionContext(ClassTestDescriptor.java:436)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$synthesizeBeforeEachMethodAdapter$14(ClassTestDescriptor.java:424)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachMethods$2(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:136)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachMethods(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:110)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform.run(JUnitPlatform.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Can somebody help my to mock **Thymeleaf** template engine?

Thank Dominique

The template engine is injected as bean in the MailService object.
Here is the MailService code:

```
@Service
public class MailService {
    @Autowired private JavaMailSender mailSender;
    @Autowired private TemplateEngine templateEngine;
    
    private static final String SUPPORT_EMAIL_ADDRESS = "Support@email.fr";
    
    public void newMailBoxMail(String pCivility, String pName, String pEmailAddress) throws MessagingException {
        // template context (model)
        final Context vContext = new Context();
        vContext.setVariable("civility", pCivility);
        vContext.setVariable("name", pName);
        vContext.setVariable("email", pEmailAddress);
        
        // create HTML from template
        final String vHtmlContent = templateEngine.process("html/NewMailbox.html", vContext);
        
        // create mail
        MimeMessage vMimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        
        MimeMessageHelper vMessage = new MimeMessageHelper(vMimeMessage, "UTF-8");
        vMessage.setSubject("Charte messagerie");
        vMessage.setFrom(SUPPORT_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
        vMessage.setTo(pEmailAddress);
        vMessage.setText(vHtmlContent, true);
        
        // send mail
        mailSender.send(vMimeMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can You show code of `MailService`? Is TemplateEngine injected as a bean in MailService?

Comment: Are you sure you need both ExtendsWith and RunWith annotations ? I think ExtendsWith is a Juint5  version of RunWith(Junit 4) .Don't think we can have both on the same test class.

Comment: Yes, TemplateEngine is injected as bean

Comment: Can you try/have you tried: `doReturn("<html>Template processed String</html>").when(templateEngine.process(any(), any()));`? This method is also relevant to the question: `templateEngine.process(A, B)`

Comment: @SandeepLakdawala I copied `@extendWith` and `@RunWith` annotation from a sample found on internet. If I remove `@RunWith`, I can't run my test anymore. If I remove `@extendsWith` no mocking is done.

Comment: @RobEvans: I got a compile error. TemplateEngine have multiple process methods with 2 args :(

Comment: so then specifically you need to avoid using `any()` and use `anyString()`, `any(SpecificObject.class)` - so that the calls can be matched exactly to the correct method signature of the method you're attempting to mock. Null pointer to the `Template` suggests no Template to use was not specified/configured for the Test run.. Can you confirm?

Comment: I'd amend the mocking matchers to: `.when(templateEngine.process(anyString(), any(Context.class)));` Since you're passing a `Context` object rather than an `IContext` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito does not allow to test final methods and process() of Template Engine is final.

However you can make it work. Just in you `/src/test/resources` create directory `mockito-extensions`. Inside create file `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` with given content: `mock-maker-inline`.

That works.